# Python3 how to assign an ordinal value from a column and create multiple rows based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, etl

How can i transform below dataset by creating new column in ColA value split by comma "," and assigning its ordering value. PLus createing multiple rows for ColB split by space " " ? While create another column for indexing

Current Dataframe

```
Record_No         COlA           ColB
 1                A1,A2,A3       B1 B2 
 2                A4,A5          B3
 3                A1,A4,A2
```

Expected Result

```
NewNo.  Record_No         A1    A2    A3   A4   A5     ColB
  1        1               1     2    3    0    0       B1
  2        1               1     2    3    0    0       B2
  3        2               0     0    0    1    2       B3 
  4        3               1     3    0    2    0       Blank
```

Comment: Please check the answers @foy

Answer (score 1):

You must use:

- `str.split` to convert the strings from `COlA` and `ColB` into lists
- `explode` to convert those lists into rows
- `get_dummies` to build the indicator columns containing 0 an 1 values
- `group-by.sum` to group above rows per Record_No,ColB pair

The hard part, is that you want to use the ordering value and not just 1 in the Ai columns. So I would use `enumerate` to get that ordering value and use it to multiply what `get_dummies` will provide.

Possible code:

```
# explode the "lists" and keep the ordering value for COlA
result = df.assign(COlA=df['COlA'].str.split(',').apply(
    lambda x: list(enumerate(x, 1)))).assign(ColB=df['ColB'].str.split(' ')
                                             ).explode('COlA').explode('ColB')

# separate the ordering value from the value itself in different columns
result['Coeff'] = result['COlA'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
result['COlA'] = result['COlA'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

It gives:

```
   Record_No COlA  ColB  Coeff
0          1   A1    B1      1
0          1   A1    B2      1
0          1   A2    B1      2
0          1   A2    B2      2
0          1   A3    B1      3
0          1   A3    B2      3
1          2   A4    B3      1
1          2   A5    B3      2
2          3   A1  None      1
2          3   A4  None      2
2          3   A2  None      3
```

Let us go on:

```
# build the indicator values and replace None with Blank in ColB
result = pd.get_dummies(result.fillna('Blank'), columns=['COlA'])

# multiply the indicator value by the ordering value
result.iloc[:, 3:] = np.transpose(np.transpose(result.iloc[:, 3:].values
                                             ) * result.Coeff.values)
```

We have:

```
   Record_No   ColB  Coeff  COlA_A1  COlA_A2  COlA_A3  COlA_A4  COlA_A5
0          1     B1      1        1        0        0        0        0
0          1     B2      1        1        0        0        0        0
0          1     B1      2        0        2        0        0        0
0          1     B2      2        0        2        0        0        0
0          1     B1      3        0        0        3        0        0
0          1     B2      3        0        0        3        0        0
1          2     B3      1        0        0        0        1        0
1          2     B3      2        0        0        0        0        2
2          3  Blank      1        1        0        0        0        0
2          3  Blank      2        0        0        0        2        0
2          3  Blank      3        0        3        0        0        0
```

Just rename the columns, group values and drop the now useless Coeff colum

```
result = result.drop(columns='Coeff').rename(
    columns=lambda x: x.replace('COlA_', '')).groupby(
        ['Record_No', 'ColB']).sum().reset_index()
```

We get the expected values:

```
   Record_No   ColB  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
0          1     B1   1   2   3   0   0
1          1     B2   1   2   3   0   0
2          2     B3   0   0   0   1   2
3          3  Blank   1   3   0   2   0
```

If you need the NewNo. column, it is now trivial:

```
result = result.rename_axis('NewNo.').reset_index()
```

And we finaly have:

```
   NewNo.  Record_No   ColB  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
0       0          1     B1   1   2   3   0   0
1       1          1     B2   1   2   3   0   0
2       2          2     B3   0   0   0   1   2
3       3          3  Blank   1   3   0   2   0
```

Comment: You could use `prefix='', prefix_sep=''` in `pd.get_dummies` to simplify some statements.

Comment: thank you for your help Serge, however, the first record NewNo.0 Record_No 1 has A1 >1 instead of 1 –

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in three simple steps.

First, create an exploded view of `ColB`

```
df['ColB'] = df.ColB.str.split(' ')
exp_df = df.explode('ColB')
```

Then, create columns with the index of items in `ColA`

```
index_df = (
    exp_df.COlA.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
        {v:i for i, v in enumerate(x)}
    )
).add(1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Then concatenate both

```
pd.concat([exp_df, index_df], axis=1)
```

Output

```
   Record_No          COlA  ColB  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
0          1  [A1, A2, A3]    B1   1   2   3   0   0
0          1  [A1, A2, A3]    B2   1   2   3   0   0
1          2      [A4, A5]    B3   0   0   0   1   2
2          3  [A1, A4, A2]  None   1   3   0   2   0
```

Note: You could drop the `COlA` if you want.